# const_missing': uninitialized constant Rack::IpRestrictor (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack, middleware

Why the error?

Here's the setup:

**config/initializers/rack_ip_restrictor.rb**

```
Rack::IpRestrictor.configure do
  respond_with [403, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, '']

  ips_for :test do
    add '127.0.0.1'
    add '127.0.0.2/8'
  end

  restrict /^\/admin/, '/admin', :only => :test
end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.middleware.use Rack::IpRestrictor.middleware
    ...
  end
```

**/lib/rack_ip_restrictor.rb**

```
require 'ipaddr'
require 'active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options'

# namespace Rack
module Rack
  # namespace IpRestrictor
  module IpRestrictor
    class << self
      attr_reader :config

      # @see Config#initialize
      def configure(&block)
        @config = IpRestrictor::Config.new
        @config.instance_eval &block
      end

      # Rack middleware
      # @return [Middleware] The configured plug & play Rack middleware
      def middleware
        IpRestrictor::Middleware
      end
    end
  end
end

require 'rack_ip_restrictor/ip_group'
require 'rack_ip_restrictor/middleware'
require 'rack_ip_restrictor/config'
require 'rack_ip_restrictor/restriction'
```

Any idea why rails can't find Rack::IpRestrictor ?

Thanks

Comment: Trying to integrate this into my app w/o using the gem as I need to do a lot of customization --- https://github.com/phatworx/rack_ip_restrictor

Answer (score 0):

You're not requiring this file anywhere. That is why it cannot find the constant. Files in the `lib` directory are not automatically loaded in Rails 3. Require this file manually.